# Update SQL statement with special characters and Carriage return in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, special-characters

I need to Update certain records in Oracle, Update statement looks like

- Columnname = expense
- tablename = ExpensesTable

This is an example:

UPDATE EXPENSESTABLE SET EXPENSE = 'Monthly Expenses - set of individual break down for current month and forecast for the next couple of months.
Number of exclusive transacation% current month% Wrong yearly expenses set of break down for the next couple of years'

WHERE EXPENSE LIKE '%Monthly Expenses - set of individual break down for current month and forecast for the next couple of months.
Number of exclusive transaction% current month% the Correct yearly expenses set of break down for the next couple of years%'

How can this be done?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do.  Your description is not very clear.  Sample data and desired results can help.

Comment: I am going to make a guess. The answer is NO. Here's why. That column `expense` looks like it will be numeric so you cannot update a numeric column to hold a long string. But I really think you are asking the wrong question; what you seem to want is a DISPLAY of the data inside that long string - and this is possible. As stated above, please provide sample data and desired result